# Vim syntax highlighting: make region only match on one line

Tags: unix, vim

I have defined a custom file type with these lines:

```
syn region SubSubtitle start=+=+ end=+=+
highlight SubSubtitle ctermbg=black ctermfg=DarkGrey

syn region Subtitle start=+==+ end=+==+
highlight Subtitle ctermbg=black ctermfg=DarkMagenta

syn region Title start=+===+ end=+===+
highlight Title ctermbg=black ctermfg=yellow

syn region MasterTitle start=+====+ end=+====+
highlight MasterTitle cterm=bold term=bold ctermbg=black ctermfg=LightBlue
```

I enclose all of my headings in this kind of document like this:

```
==== Biggest Heading ==== // this will be bold and light blue

  ===Sub heading === // this will be yellow 

    bla bla bla  // this will be normally formatted
```

However right now when ever I use an equals sign in my code it thinks that it is a title.  Is there anyway that I can force a match to be only on one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**: My previous answer was wrong, you can do this with a region, just do

```
syn region SubSubtitle start=+=+ end=+=+ oneline
```

See `:help syn-oneline` and `:help syn-arguments`.  Guess it shows that I can't actually run vim right now, hunh?

---

**Previous answer**

According to my reading of the [:help syntax](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html), <s>there's no way to do this with a region</s>.  However, you could do this with a syn-match:

```
syn match SubSubtitle /=\@<!=[^=]*==\@!/
```

The `/=\@<!/` says there's no `=` immediately before your match, and the `/=\@!/` says there's no `=` immediately after, so this matches exactly one `=`, a bunch of non-`=` (not including newlines - to include newlines it would have to be `\_[^=]`), then exactly one `=`.

The rest are similar

```
syn match Subtitle    /=\@<!=\{2}[^=]*=\{2}=\@!/
syn match Title       /=\@<!=\{3}[^=]*=\{3}=\@!/
syn match MasterTitle /=\@<!=\{4}[^=]*=\{4}=\@!/
```

You can still do matches within syn-matches, so if you have any nesting going on, it will still work.

For example

```
syn match Todo /\<TODO\>/ containedin=SubSubtitle,Subtitle,Title,MasterTitle contained
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks, I knew that I saw that oneline somewhere when browsing the vim help but you can never find things when you need them.